# Detaching process in golang and waiting till it exits

Tags: linux, go

I was looking for way to run command in go app e.g. `sleep 10 %% echo "Test"`,
detach it (I want that command to outlive closing terminal or my program) and wait till it exits

I tried to spawn command using: `cmd := exec.Command("command", "arg1", "arg2")` then `cmd.Process.Release()`, but after releasing process I noticed that now I cannot call `cmd.Wait()` or `cmd.Process.Wait()`, because it throws this error: `invalid argument`

Comment: `Process.Release` is unnecessary and unhelpful. It doesn't change whether your process survives its parent's exit (at least, not at the OS level, where all that matters is that none of stdin, stdout and stderr are FIFOs where the other side goes to the parent, and that the parent doesn't affirmatively send a fatal signal to the child on exit). Don't do it.

Comment: To make the child outlive the closing of the terminal as well, you need to make sure stdin, stdout and stderr aren't connected to that terminal. Hook them up to a file, or to `/dev/null`. (Obviously, you won't see the output from the echo unless the place you routed stdout actually retains content).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is important for me to redirect `std*` to the terminal. Do you think piping e.g. cmd.Stdout to `/dev/stdout` would help me with detaching from terminal?

Comment: @Bader What you're trying to do is impossible. You have incompatible requirements.

Comment: If `/dev/stdout` refers to a terminal, a file descriptor pointing to it will become unusable, typically throwing fatal errors, after the next attempted write after the terminal closes (if you don't get a signal before that point). You can write to the terminal, or you can survive the exit of that terminal; unless the program you're starting is written specifically to ignore losing its terminal, you can't do both.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fortunately the program which I am trying to run is my own app (also written in go) so if there is need I can modify it's source code
Do I correctly understand that you propose me to write my own print function which will ignore all errors?

Comment: Since it's Go, you could also _decline to check_ the results of print functions you don't want to be fatal; as long as you ignore those errors, and ignore SIGHUP (and maybe SIGPIPE, if you want to also survive losing the other end of a pipeline as opposed to _only_ losing a terminal), you should be okay. See https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal re: configuring signal handling in Go.

Comment: BTW, I'd strongly suggest having an alternate logging destination -- whether that's the syslog socket, or a file on disk, or whatever else -- to allow better debugging of what happens after your terminal is gone.

Comment: In serious real-world applications I probably wouldn't have your program running directly in a terminal at all, but would use something like `systemd-run` to kick it off as a background service, with logs being copied _from_ the service into the terminal by a separate process -- as in the systemd case with `journalctl`; see examples combining the two in https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-run.html